SigScale OCS HSS Integration
Hi anyone here tried working with Sigscale OCS?
How SigscaleOCS integrates to HSS? As I've read from the documentation you can configure the hss_realm, how to add hss_realm environment variable in Sigscale configuration? Is it possible to pass this in docker?
